# É possível pegar o valor da chave de um JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, react

```
{
   "id":1,
   "nome":"Alexandre Gama",
   "endereco":"R. Qualquer"
}
```

Eu estou utilizando ReactJS, e eu preciso armazenar o nome das chaves de um objeto JSON, guardando a estrutura de qualquer objeto que for passado. A ideia é criar um cabeçalho de uma tabela de acordo com o nome das chaves do JSON, que podem variar. Só que eu não sei como armazenar o nome da chave ao invés do valor dela. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Por exemplo, no código acima eu iria precisar armazenar: "nome" e "endereço" ao invés de seus respectivos valores.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando o método   [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Para o seu caso seria algo assim:

```
const a = {
   "id":1,
   "nome":"Alexandre Gama",
   "endereco":"R. Qualquer"
}
Objects.keys(a)
// Array(3) [ "id", "nome", "endereco" ]
```

Object.keys() retorna um array cujo os  elementos são strings correspondentes para a propriedade enumerável encontrada diretamente sobre o objeto. A ordenação das propriedades é a mesma que a dada pelo loop sobre as propriedades do objeto manualmente.

Comment: Valeu! Deu certo